# Как открыть всплывающее окно при закрытии вкладки браузера

Tags: javascript

Как открыть всплывающее окно при закрытии вкладки браузера?
К примеру пользователь заходит на сайт, и после закрывает вкладку браузера, как в таком случаи открыть модальное окно типа "Вы покидаете сайт" и 2 кнопки "Остаться на сайте" и "Покинуть сайт"?

Предполагаю что это делается при помощи простых окошек javascript.
Спасибо!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser

Comment: А вы видели рабочий пример хоть раз? Если нет, то это и будет ответом на вопрос.

Comment: @Ъь_, и не один раз видел.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
window.onunload = function()
{
    return confirm('Вы хотите покинуть сайт?')
}
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return confirm('Точно хотите выйти?');
}
```

Никогда не баловался этим, итог получился интересный, каждый как хочет так и понимает:

**Opera 12.11** - игнорирует (вроде бы после выхода 10й версии, точно не помню, когда ввели фичу закрытия окна при активном alert() и confirm()), закрывает не спрашивая

**Chrome 23.0** - довольно интересно, спрашивает выйти или нет, но не выводит confirm()

**Firefox 17.0.1** - тоже прикольно, выводит confirm(), но ему без разницы true/false, затем сам спрашивает уйти или остатся.

IE - не проверял, из-за этого не стану в винду перезагружатся, сам опробуете.

Практическое применение мало где нужно, по большей части это будет раздражать пользователя, но если происходит обработка очень важной информации к примеру платеж в магазине, то это стоящая фича, а в остальном не советую

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onunload = function()
{
     return confirm('Вы хотите покинуть сайт?')
}
```

По идее, должно помочь.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
     return confirm('Точно хотите выйти?');
}
```

Comment: работает, но только окошко выдается при переходе по ссылкам, как это можно фильтровать ?